# OpenSAML C++ signature validation : crash reading public key from certificate

Tags: c++, openssl, saml, signature

I have created a SAML Request and got Response with signature from SAML Server. I want to validate this using the token signing certificate (containing RSA public key).

I am using OpenSSL libraries to load the certificate from file, but I am getting some junk values in the RSA structure, which is eventually crashing when I try to create `XSECCryptoKey` key.

Below is the sample I am using to get RSA keys.

```
const char* certpath = "sample.cer";
EVP_PKEY *key;
BIO* in=BIO_new(BIO_s_file_internal());
BIO_read_filename(in, certpath);
X509* cer=PEM_read_bio_X509(in, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
BIO_free(in);
key = X509_get_pubkey(cer);
XSECCryptoKey* ret=new OpenSSLCryptoKeyRSA(pkey); //crashing, because of improper values in RSA keys (key->pkey.rsa->n,key->pkey.rsa->d etc)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your certificate a PEM certificate? If so you might want to include it into the question. Please show the precise error, "crashing" is not a good error description.

Comment: Anyone has implemented certificate validation using CPP?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of openssl libraries. It works fine with ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll (0.98) version, but not with 1.0.1 and 1.0.2.